# Creation of Rule Class from the json in a generic way

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a json like below and I am trying to create a class for this. What would be the best way to represent this.

For example :  A Rule object consists of conditions, like "Any Condition"  or "All condition" and they can nested like the below example.

A condition in its simplest form is Class with 3 properties : Fact, Operator, Value.

I am struggling with representing the All and Any Conditions which can be nested.  Can some give some idea on how I can represent this in my Rule Class.

```
{
    "conditions": {
        "any": [{
            "all": [{
                "fact": "gameDuration",
                "operator": "equal",
                "value": 40
            }, {
                "fact": "personalFoulCount",
                "operator": "greaterThanInclusive",
                "value": 5
            }]
        }, {
            "all": [{
                "fact": "gameDuration",
                "operator": "equal",
                "value": 48
            }, {
                "fact": "personalFoulCount",
                "operator": "greaterThanInclusive",
                "value": 6
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: In visual studio, you can use "paste special" which has a JSON => classes option. Does that work?

Comment: Paste your JSON here: [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp). You get back a class structure. You have just a RootObject and 3 class objects: `conditions` is a `List<any>` and `any` is a `List<all>`. Change the name of the `any` and `all` properties, to avoid *confusion*, using a `[JsonProperty()]` attribute. That's all.